# How to remove vertical pipe before line break in flexbox container

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a dropdown menu container that is styled using flexbox.  I have a vertical pipe after each list item and want to remove the pipe from the last item before the line break so as to avoid the dangling "|".

Any css wizardry to make this happen?

Here is the staging site: https://myersbrierkelly.djykrmv8-liquidwebsites.com/

Click on "Practice Areas" and you will see it on the dropdown.

Comment: No this is not possible with CSS. Css cannot detect line breaks or overflow. You need media queries or javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar .dropdown-menu li:last-child::after {
    content: '';
}
```

Comment: This only removes the very last one in the list but doesn't address the other two rows.

Comment: I guess you'll have to target the last `<li>` elements on each line individually by their id's then. It's not ideal, since it's not dynamic, but otherwise you'd have to split the `<nav>` over three `<ul>` 's, but that's not very nice either.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to go the javascript route by comparing each list item's offset top and finding the break based on that and adding a class of wrapped.

```
var detectWrap = function(className) {
  
  var wrappedItems = [];
  var prevItem = {};
  var currItem = {};
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    currItem = items[i].getBoundingClientRect();
    if (prevItem && prevItem.top < currItem.top) {
      wrappedItems.push(items[i]);
    }
    prevItem = currItem;
  };
  
  return wrappedItems;

}

window.onload = function(e){
  var wrappedItems = detectWrap('menu-item-object-practice-area');
  for (var k = 0; k < wrappedItems.length; k++) {
    wrappedItems[k].className = "wrapped";
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Use nth-child(n) to select specific child element where you don't want the vertical pipe, like this

```
.navbar .dropdown-menu li:nth-child(4)::after, 
.navbar .dropdown-menu li:nth-child(7)::after, 
.navbar .dropdown-menu li:nth-child(10)::after {
    content: "";
 }
```

The nth-child(n) selector selects the nth child element.

Comment: This removes the very last one but not the other two rows unfortunately.

Comment: [EDIT] Use nth-child() selector.

Comment: I have updated the answer. nth-child(x), where x can be 1,2,3... can select specific child. for example, nth-child(2) selects the second child.